# Destination Host Unreachable on local wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, ping

I have two computers on my local wireless network. I am trying to set up an ssh server on one of them (computer 2). When I ping the local IP of computer 2 from computer 1, it prints Destination Host Unreachable. However, when I use wireshark on computer 2, I can see the packets from computer 1's IP address. What do I need to do in order to make the ping succeed? Both computers are Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you show the outpuf of the command `ifconfig` in both computers?

Answer (score 1):

Is the firewall disabled on computer 2? You can disable the firewall with `sudo ufw disable`

I would also recommend you run a tcpdump on both machines while trying to ping or SSH as well to identify if packets are making it to computer 2. You can use the following tcpdump command to isolate ICMP (ping) and port 22.

`sudo tcpdump -i any icmp or port 22`

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: On computer 1, `tcpdump` gives `ICMP host computer_2_IP unreachable`. computer 2 doesn't show anything with `tcpdump`, even though wireshark shows it hitting.